# How to select shapes in a word document and paste them in another word document using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to copy just the shapes (the shapes are drawing canvas) from one section of a word document "A" to a section of a word document B.

I made the next code:

```
Sub CopyInfo()
  Dim A_Path, Prop As String 'path of A,title
  Dim dlgSelectFile As FileDialog 'Object for selecting path
  'Create File dialog oject
  Set dlgSelectFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  With dlgSelectFile
  .Filters.Clear
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
  A_Path = .SelectedItems(1) 'saving selected document
  End With

'Open ESI
Dim ADoc As Document
Set ADoc = Documents.Open(A_Path)

Dim MyRange As Range

'State Diagram
Documents(ADoc).Activate 'Activate A document
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Content
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find 'find logical description heading
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Logical Description"
    .Style = "Heading 2"
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    Set MyRange = .Duplicate.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel") 'set range of heading section
    MyRange.Start = MyRange.Paragraphs.First.Range.End
    MyRange.SetRange Start:=MyRange.Start, End:=MyRange.End - 1
        For i = 1 To MyRange.ShapeRange.Count 'search and copy/paste only images
            MyRange.ShapeRange.Item(MyRange.ShapeRange.Count + 1 - i).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ThisDocument.Activate 'Activate document B
            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="StateDiagram" 'go to bookmark where i want to paste images
            Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine 'paste on document B
            Documents(ADoc).Activate 'Activate A document
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

In my code, from document "B", I open document "A", and set MyRange in the section I want to get the shapes from (which is a content in a Heading). Then for all the shapes in MyRange I copy them and paste them in Document B one by one (starting from last shape to first one).

The problem is that sometimes it does copy the figures, and sometimes it doesn't.
I think the problem is in selection.copy, since it does select the shapes, but the clipboard remains empty. Does anyone knows where could the problem be at?

Note: I don't know if this has something to do, but it does copy them when document "A" is already opened and my cursor is below the last shape. I've tried it in many different "A" documents and the same happens.

I'm new at VBA, so I'm sorry if the solution to my problem is really obvious or if I didn't  make myself clear.

Comment: Are you running this code from Excel? If so, `Selection` refers to Excel, not Word.

Comment: `Range.Select Selection.Copy` can be simplified to `Range.Copy`. and improve `Selection.Paste` to `Range.Paste`. By removing the reliance on `Selection` you improve the accuracy and reliability of your code. For example `ThisDocument.Range.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="StateDiagram").PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine`

Comment: @Toddleson - except that there is no `Copy` method for either a `Shape` or a `ShapeRange`. Of course, if the heading range in the source document only contains shapes then `targetRange.FormattedText = sourceRange.FormattedText` would work and avoid use of the clipboard.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I'm running the code with word, does the selection object doesn't work with word? And unfortunately the heading range also contains text.

Comment: @Toddleson, first of all thank you for your answer. As Timothy said, I can't copy an item of the ShapeRange directly that is why I select it, but I'm thinking that maybe I can set another range that only includes 1 shaperange item, and copy this range.

Comment: `Selection` works with Word. I asked the question because you added the excel tag to your question. When you ask questions in future please be careful to only use tags that are directly related to your question.

Comment: If the State Diagram is something standard you could save it as a Building Block in the document template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand why, but I realize that the shapes were only copied if the section where the shapes are located is display. So, in the for loop, before selecting each shape, I use `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView` for displaying each shape, I then set a timer of one second for word to perform this task, and then I select and copy the Shape.

```
For i = 1 To MyRange.ShapeRange.Count 'search and copy/paste only images
        ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView MyRange.ShapeRange.Item(MyRange.ShapeRange.Count + 1 -i), false
        StartTime = Timer
        Do While Timer < StartTime + 1
           DoEvents
        Loop
        MyRange.ShapeRange.Item(MyRange.ShapeRange.Count + 1 - i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ThisDocument.Activate 'Activate document B
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="StateDiagram" 'go to bookmark where i want to paste images
        Selection.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine 'paste on document B
        Documents(ADoc).Activate 'Activate A document
    Next i
```